# When can we expect 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) to be moved to "old-releases"?

Tags: 12.04, updates

The [EOL Process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EndOfLifeProcess) has some fairly extensive details on what would happen after a distro would reach EOL.

One of the main outcomes is that the distro would be moved to "old-releases.ubuntu.com". Oddly enough we are a few days past EOL and the release still doesn't show up on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

Does anyone have any insights into when something like this usually happens?

Answer (score 1):

It is a manual action so whenever the person in charge does it. And there is not a schedule for this to happen.

If you go 1 level up on your link you can see that [12.04 and 12.04.4 are already there](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) and are also on the current releases page. But 12.04.5 will follow soon and it will get removed from the current releases.

Comment: … and afaik there's no schedule for this change.

Comment: 12.04 is already there

Comment: Hmm… Ctrl+F `precise` on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ shows no result.

Comment: Maybe the one responsible is amongst the people fired :-P

Comment: Ctrl+F `precise` on old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists works now :)